# Multiple UITableViews - Memory management recommendations

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, memory-management, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageControl with lots of pages (around 50) each of which represents a UITableView which has around 250 rows. I add the UITableView subview on the UIScrollView on demand as to keep the memory usage at low levels. However if you browse to all pages and scroll down through all the TableViews the memory usage shoots up making the application really slow. Please give me your insights on how to keep the memory usage as low as possible. I have thought of removing all other subviews except the one in view however since the content of the tableviews is dynamically loaded using MSXML this is not really convenient. Please advice.

Thank you in advance